# Removing directories: Shell vs. File Manager

Tags: shell, rm, file-manager, thunar

I've noticed that some graphical file manages such as Thunar allow you to remove any directory as long as you are the owner of this directory -- even if this directory contains a sub directory which you do not have write access to. On the other hand, `rm -rf` won't allow you to delete such a directory (Permission denied).

*Example:*

```
dirOwnedByUser
└──dirOwnedByRoot

$ rm -rf dirOwnedByUser 
rm: cannot remove 'dirOwnedByUser/dirOwnedByRoot: Permission denied
```

1. Could some explain this to me?
2. Is there a way to delete such a directory in Shell?

Comment: have a look at http://www.catchlinux.com/permissions-primer/

one way to delete will be as root user.. try `sudo rm -rf dirOwnedByUser` and give root password when prompted

Comment: If `rm` can't do it, Thunar can't do it either. (Unless you give Thunar root privileges of course.) Are you sure you attempted to remove the same directory? Are you sure you removed the directory, rather than moving it to the trash (which doesn't touch the subdirectories at all and therefore isn't affected by their permissions)?

Comment: This is what I do: I create a user directory `data`. Then I run a Docker container which creates a volume `share` in `data`. `share` is owned by root and therefore can't be *directly* deleted by the user (neither using Thunar nor using `rm`). But the user can delete `data` using Thunar. Following this "workaround", the user can *indirectly* remove `data/share`.